# Binomial modelling, testing and Bonferroni

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, bonferroni, hypergeometric-distribution, multivariate-distribution

I am currently trying to validate an implementation that is supposed to randomly assign a certain number of tags to users who enter a platform. The variable of interest here for me is the sum of all assignments of each tag across all users and I want to check if they are equally distributed across all tags.

I modeled the process in the following way:

Let $X_{i,j}$ denote the assignment status (1 if assigned, 0 otherwise) of tag i (i=1,…,N) for user j (j=1,…,m). Each tag can only be assigned once per user, they are all equally likely, and a total of n tags is to be assigned to each user.

1. Then for each user j the random variable ($X_{.,j}$) follows a multivariate hypergeometric distribution with parameters $K = (1,…,1)$, $N = N$, and $n = n$ (using [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution) notation here).
2. So the mean and variance for each tag i for every user j is $E(X_i) = \frac{nK_i}{N}$ and $Var(X_i) = \frac{K_i}{N}(1 - \frac{K_i}{N})n\frac{N-n}{N-1}$ which in this case ($K_i = 1$ for all i) reduces nicely to $E(X_i) = \frac{n}{N}$ and $Var(X_i) = \frac{n}{N}(1-\frac{n}{N})$
3. So I assume that each variable $X_{i,j}$ is Bernoulli with $p = \frac{n}{N}$. **I don’t have a formal argument here** only a very strong intuition. I guess/hope there is a theorem that might rescue me here?
4. If the above holds the vector of sums for each tag variable $X_{i,j}$ across all users each of the random variables $\bar{X_{i}} = \sum_{j=1}^{m} X_{i,j}$ would be binomial.

The reasoning above is a little sketchy, especially the Bernoulli part, but I think there is probably a more elegant way of arriving at the binomial distribution for $\bar{X_{i}}$ (or I am just plainly wrong)?

Assuming $\bar{X_{i}}$ is in fact binomial the next logical thing in my quest to validate the random assignment process would be to run binomial tests for the number of successes $\bar{X_{i}}$ for every $i$.

Now while doing exactly that I got some significant p-values (< 0.05) indicating something is not right with the implementation. However after some thinking about the issue this seems to be a case where a Bonferroni correction should be applied, right? The definition when to use it is somewhat blurry (again using [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) here) but in my opinion the setup above qualifies as a “hypotheses family”. This is very relevant since in this case the application of Bonferroni would eliminate the significance of my results. The number of tests I run varies between 4 and 9 (there are different scenarios I'm testing)